# Set-new-password form, including validation

Tags: validation, typescript, angular-2+

I've got to make a form using Bootstrap and Angular, which validates the following requirements:

- Old password, new password and confirm password are mandatory fields.
- New password has to be equal confirm password.

[image: Screenshot]

My HTML-code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="old_password">Old Password</label>
      <input formControlName="old_password" #oldPassword id="old_password" name="old_password" type="password" (keyup)="oldPasswordChanged(oldPassword.value)" class="form-control">
      <div *ngIf="form.get('old_password')?.touched && form.get('old_password')?.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('old_password')?.errors['required']">Old Password is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">New Password</label>
      <input formControlName="new_password" id="new_password" #newPassword type="password" (keyup)="newPasswordChanged(newPassword.value)" class="form-control">
      <div *ngIf="form.get('new_password')?.touched && form.get('new_password')?.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('new_password')?.errors['required']">New Password is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
      <input formControlName="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" #confirmPassword type="password" (keyup)="confirmPasswordChanged(confirmPassword.value)" class="form-control">
      <div *ngIf="form.get('confirm_password')?.touched && form.get('confirm_password')?.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="form.get('confirm_password')?.errors['required']">Password-Confirmation is required</div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="doesPasswordsNotMatch" class="alert alert-danger">Passwords do not match!</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Change Password</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The TypeScript-component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  oldPassword = ""
  newPassword = ""
  sConfirmPassword = ""
  doesPasswordsNotMatch = false

  form = new FormGroup({
    old_password: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    new_password: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    confirm_password: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required
    ])
  });

  oldPasswordChanged(value: string) {
    this.oldPassword = value
  }

  newPasswordChanged(value: string) {
    this.newPassword = value
  }

  confirmPasswordChanged(value: string) {
    this.sConfirmPassword = value
    if (this.newPassword !== this.sConfirmPassword) {
      this.doesPasswordsNotMatch = true;
    } else {
      this.doesPasswordsNotMatch = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Are there flaws in my code?**

**Is there a better way to accomplish the validation?**

Other hints and comments concerning my code are appreciated as well.

Comment: You can handle passwords match check by writing custom validation function. (linked to FormGroup, not FormControl)